# Excluding entries from MySQL table using both NOT IN and NOT LIKE

Tags: mysql

A table in my MySQL DB holds IP addresses in short hex format i.e.  'C0A80001'. I want to select the 1000 most recent entries to this table exluding any entry of 'NULL', '8.8.8.8', '192.168.*.*', '10.*.*.*' and the class B network (which I have yet to work out how to exclude).

Without the exlusions I have:

```
SELECT IP_Address
FROM Event_Table
ORDER BY Time_Created
DESC LIMIT 0, 1000;
```

Which, of course, works nicely. It's when I add the exclusions that I encounter errors:

```
SELECT IP_Address
FROM event_table
sourceIPAddr NOT IN ('NULL', '08080808') AND
```

*(To exclude 'NULL' entries and '8.8.8.8')*

```
IP_Address NOT LIKE 'C0A8%%' AND
```

*(To exclude '192.168.*.*)*

```
IP_Address NOT LIKE '0A%%'
```

*(To exclude '10.*.*.*)*

```
ORDER BY Time_Created
DESC LIMIT 0, 1000;
```

Comment: i don't see the `WHERE` keyword. Did you have forgot to put it in after the `event_table` entry ?

Comment: What are the errors you're encountering?

Comment: It was the missing 'WHERE', I feel stupid now ! Anyway, thanks for noticing, Karel.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to store your IP addresses and netmasks as integer values if you really want to save space. It's much more convenient than hex values (I wonder why you chose to do so anyhow).

MySQL offers two functions for this, [INET_ATON()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) to convert IP addresses to an integer value, and for the reverse [INET_NTOA()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa).

To exclude NULL and 8.8.8.8

```
SELECT IP_Address
FROM event_table
WHERE
INET_NTOA(sourceIPAddr) IS NOT NULL 
AND INET_NTOA(sourceIPAddr) != '8.8.8.8';
```

To exclude 192.168.*.*

```
SELECT IP_Address
FROM event_table
WHERE
INET_NTOA(sourceIPAddr) NOT LIKE '192.168.%';
```

To exclude 10.*.*.*

```
SELECT IP_Address
FROM event_table
WHERE
INET_NTOA(sourceIPAddr) NOT LIKE '10.%';
```

`%` in `LIKE` means "zero or more times any given charcater, really any, also .". You can of course use

```
SELECT IP_Address
FROM event_table
WHERE
INET_NTOA(sourceIPAddr) NOT LIKE '10.%.%.%';
```

to make sure, there are dots in between, but there's no need. And using something like `LIKE ('whatever%%%')` is no difference. To search for a single character, that must be there (there's no "one character 0 or 1 time"), you can use the underscore `_`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's actually a DB I'm taking a feed from, not mine so I only have read only access. I have a script to convert the hex into proper IP format afterwards - I just need this select statement to get the IPs in the first place (while excluding the ones I mentioned).